# Under what condition l2-norm of a vector X is always geq than the inner product of X and k?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given that `x` and `k` are both n-dimensional real-numbered vectors. What condition should vector `k` satisfy 
s.t. for any `x`, $$\left\| x\right\| _{2}\geq k^{T}x$$ is always true?

I can think of the answer (l2 norm of k should less or equal than 1) from a geometric perspective. But I can't think of a solution from pure algebra perspective -- needing help on this.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy My professor mentioned Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. I know that theorem, but I don't know to apply it in this case.

Comment: Do you know the formula $k^T x = \lVert k \rVert \lVert x \rVert \cos\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the angle between $k$ and $x$?

Comment: @OnDragi Thanks for mentioning this. I got the result ||k||2≤1 using this method. Trying to think from a pure algebra perspective.

Comment: I'd say that Cauchy-Schwartz inequality is ``purely algebraic''. It says that $\lVert k \rVert \lVert x \rVert \geq \left| k^T x\right|$ with equality iff $x$ and $k$ are linearly dependent. Can you see how you get the same thing from that?

Comment: @OnDragi My professor mentioned Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. I know that theorem, but I don't know to apply it in this case. Thanks for specifying how you solve it using Cauchy-Schwartz.